# Dynamically Updating A Fragment Call

Tags: java, android, string, variables

I want to initiate several fragments with in an activity based on their name where 'i' is a number so... DummySection1Fragment, DummySection2Fragment, DummySection3Fragment etc. how ever I'm getting issues where I try and pull the value through to create the call. I have included the basic static call and the one that I have created my self based on what I know from the JavaScript world ( I bet that's my problem).

I'd appreciate any help ( while I still look my self ) on the best way to do this as I suspect its a potential method I'll use again and again.

Current Static Code

```
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
```

Error : Invalid character constant

```
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    Fragment fragment = new 'DummySection' + i + 'Fragment'();
```

Full Code

```
/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to one of the primary
 * sections of the app.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 6;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase();
            case 1: return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase();
            case 2: return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase();
            case 3: return getString(R.string.title_section4).toUpperCase();
            case 4: return getString(R.string.title_section5).toUpperCase();
            case 5: return getString(R.string.title_section6).toUpperCase();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I advise highly against this app behavior**. What if you want to remove #3 later, and have items #4 through #17? Or perhaps you need to add one between #6 and #7. That's a lot of renaming (assuming you're maintaining order).

I'd suggest giving them proper names, and instantiating them by hand. If you do this, you can store them in an `ArrayList<Fragment>`, then return `.get(i)`.

If you're absolutely 100% determined to do your method instead, you should be able to do it like this:

```
Class clazz = Class.forName("DummySection" + i + "Fragment"); // Use ", not '
Fragment frag = (Fragment) clazz.newInstance();
```

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts Eric.... currently playing with some of the ADT examples.... I've pasted the full adapter above. TBH I'm tempted to build from blank so I know whats going in rather than editing....

Comment: The way it's set up already, it sends an argument *to* the `Fragment` telling it what number it is. So, each one is the same `DummySectionFragment`, but behaves differently based on the `ARG_SECTION_NUMBER` argument.

Comment: Yes... how ever the example only takes that arg and prints text to the screen and changes the title. Taking a step back if I have 6 different screens I plan for - 2 are RSS, 1 text and one HTML building the logic ( if / else etc ) for that seemed the long way round rather than calling individual fragments ?

Comment: Yes, you should create your own fragments for that. But create them separately and put them in an `ArrayList` of fragments, as I said. That way, you can even reuse them. I think it definitely makes the most sense for an app situation like yours.